# Parse the date string from html in lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

```
 s = """
      <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td style="border-bottom: none">
       <span class="graytext" style="font-weight: bold;"> Reply #3 - </span>
        <span class="graytext" style="font-size: 11px">
        05/13/09  2:02am
        <br>
       </span>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
 """
```

In the HTML string I need to take out the date string.

I tried in this way

```
  import lxml
  doc = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
  doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]')
```

But this is not working. I should have to take only the Datestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is selecting the `span`, you need to grab the text from it:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]')
[<Element span at 1c9d4c8>]
```

Most queries return a sequence, I normally use a helper function that gets the first item.

```
from lxml import etree
s = """
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td style="border-bottom: none">
   <span class="graytext" style="font-weight: bold;"> Reply #3 - </span>
    <span class="graytext" style="font-size: 11px">
    05/13/09  2:02am
    <br>
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
"""
doc = etree.HTML(s)

def first(sequence,default=None):
  for item in sequence:
    return item
  return default
```

Then:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]')
[<Element span at 1c9d4c8>]
>>> doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]/text()')
['\n    05/13/09  2:02am\n    ']
>>> first(doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]/text()'),'').strip()
'05/13/09  2:02am'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of the last line:

```
print doc.xpath('//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]/text()')[0]
```

The first part of the xpath expression is correct, `//span[@class="graytext" and @style="font-size: 11px"]` selects all matching span nodes and then you need to specify what you want to select from the node. `text()` used here selects the contents of the node.